# How do I access the first/second/third... character of a string in asm x86?

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, x86

I read a string from stdin, then I want to print it at stdout and also print its first letter. How do I do that?

```
.data
mesaj: .space 11                   # the string to be read
formatScanf: .asciz "%s"
formatPrintf: .asciz "%s"
endl: .asciz "\n"

.text

.global main
main:

push $mesaj
push $formatScanf
call scanf
pop %ebx
pop %ebx

push $mesaj
push $formatPrintf
call printf
pop %ebx
pop %ebx

pushl $0
call fflush
popl %ebx

push $endl
push $formatPrintf
call printf
pop %ebx
pop %ebx

pushl $0
call fflush
popl %ebx

# Print the first letter of the string
movl $0, %edx
mov $mesaj, %edi
mov $4, %eax  # System call number for write
mov $1, %ebx  # File descriptor: 1 for standard output
mov $1, %ecx  # Number of bytes to print
movb (%edi), %dl  # Load the first byte (character) of the string into DL register



int $0x80      # Call the kernel to write the character

pushl $0
call fflush
popl %ebx

movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

This is some code I wrote and ran with `gcc -m32 filename.S -o filename -no-pie` and then ./filename. It correctly reads the input string and then displays it, but it completely ignores the part that deals with the first character of the string. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Load the first char and pass it to `putchar` or use `printf` with `%.1s` (since you already seem to know how to use that).

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: Do you understand what your code is doing when it does `call printf`?